# Trigger not Working

Tags: mysql, trigger

I created trigger on table `PENDING`.

Pending table has 3 columns

- uniqueId
- duration
- maxDuration

I have another table `COUNT` with 2 columns

- req_id
- total

Here is my trigger--

```
CREATE TRIGGER plus3second BEFORE INSERT
ON PENDING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE req_id varchar(25);
DECLARE total int(11);
DECLARE duration int(2);

SET req_id = SUBSTR(new.uniqueId, 1, 14);

Select total into total from COUNT where req_id = 'req_id';

IF total > 100 THEN

 SET duration = new.duration + 3;

  IF duration < new.maxDuration Then
     SET new.duration = duration;
  END IF;


END IF;


END
```

Trigger created successfully. 
I fired these queries on COUNT and PENDING-

```
insert into COUNT values ('77711422099653',200);
insert into PENDING (uniqueId, duration, maxDuration) values ('77711422099653919893277163', 3, 20);
```

But trigger not working ...Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few corrections

1. Changed local variable `total` to `given_total`
2. Changed local variable `req_id` to `given_req_id`
3. Changed local variable `duration` to `given_duration`
4. Placed Backquotes around COUNT because COUNT is a reserved word (just a precaution)

With these corrections, here is the new trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER plus3second BEFORE INSERT
ON PENDING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE given_req_id varchar(25);
DECLARE given_total int(11);
DECLARE given_duration int(2);

SET given_req_id = SUBSTR(new.uniqueId, 1, 14);

Select total into given_total from `COUNT` where req_id = given_req_id;

IF given_total > 100 THEN

 SET given_duration = new.duration + 3;

  IF given_duration < new.maxDuration Then
     SET new.duration = given_duration;
  END IF;


END IF;


END
```

What was wrong before? In your original trigger, you had `Select total into total from COUNT where req_id = 'req_id';`. That was looking for the `req_id` actually being equal to the string 'req_id'. That's why I made the other corrections, especially correction #2.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Yessssss................It's working....                    Thanks a ton..!!